# Looking for Python example to search for a Cognito identity and update attributes

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cognito

I am integrating a payment solution which uses web hooks. The payment provider is given the Cognito userid (or user sub) during checkout. Upon successful checkout, the payment provider calls a web hook which I've implemented using AWS Lambda/Gateway and Python. Within this web hook I get the payment status and the Cognito user id.

What I'd like to do next is update or set an attribute on the given Cognito user id for the subscription status.

I've found pieces of JavaScript code which seem like they get me sort of there but I am missing something from how this should work. Here is the JS code I found to search for a user:

```
var cog = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

var filter = "sub = \"" + userSub + "\"";
var req = {
    "Filter": filter,
    "UserPoolId": "your pool id" // looks like us-east-9_KDFn1cvys
};

cog.listUsers(req, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        if (data.Users.length === 1){ //as far as we search by sub, should be only one user.
            var user = data.Users[0];
            var attributes = data.Users[0].Attributes;
        } else {
            console.log("Something wrong.");
        }
    }
});
```

I need a Python version of the above... also I am not quite sure how to initialize the AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider in order to do the search. It seems like I need to have an IAM credentials set up in order to search a user identity pool, no?

Any pointers on how to search for a user in a Cognito identity pool using Python would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can search for a user with a prefix:

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
        return o.isoformat()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId='<UserPoolID>',
        Limit=1,
        Filter='given_name^=\"Xavier\"'
    )
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response['Users'], 
            sort_keys=True,
            indent=1,
            default=default)
    }
```

You will need to replace the  with your actual Cognito User Pool ID.